# Looking for a simple e-commerce plugin

Tags: plugin-recommendation, e-commerce

I looking for a simple Wordpress e-commerce plugin which will just associate a downloadable product to a post (here a custom post type) and handle the payment with Paypal and the download page.

There are a lot of different plugin but they always provide a complex catalog, create a lot of useless page and don't provide a simple way to add in my post a simple "buy now" button which go directly to payment.

Are you aware of a plugin which meets these needs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to consider [Cart66](http://cart66.com/).  I bought a single site license a few weeks back as I was looking for something along a similar line to you.  It doesn't force a bunch of bespoke templates on you, instead, you have to create each product through a custom post (which is what you are doing anyway).  However the big benefit of this is that you have near total control over how your product pages look.

Cart66 comes in two flavours - free ([Cart66 Lite](http://cart66.com/lite/)) or if you want more features and support you can try one of the site license options.

So far I've found it to be very straightforward and more flexible than a lot of the competition.  Hope this helps

Comment: I've tested cart66 lite, it's nice, I added my own shortcode to have just a button on my product page, but do you know how it works with digital downloads ? I would like to know if people will be able to download new releases of the product, what about an included access to the documentation ?

Answer (score 1):

Woo Themes just released [Woo Commerce](http://www.woothemes.com/woocommerce/) which looks to be fairly easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

I use [eshop](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/eshop/) its Nice Plugin for e-commerce and solve almost all problems.

Answer (score 0):

Theres also [Jigoshop](http://jigoshop.com) which is where WooCommerce forked from.